# how do i convert this date column into datetime format and make it the index of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having trouble in converting this date column itno datetime. And getting error of month and year only.

```
        date    spots
0   Jan 1749    58.0
1   Feb 1749    62.6
2   Mar 1749    70.0
3   Apr 1749    55.7
4   May 1749    85.0
```

Comment: please edit this into correct formatting

Comment: I agree, you should use ``` instead of ''' for code blocks.  Also you should show at the very least the data type of the date column, or preferably how you created this dataframe so that we can reproduce it

Comment: date      object
spots    float64
dtype: object

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date.astype(str), format="%b-%y")
df = df.set_index('date')
```

Comment: ValueError: time data 'Jan-00' does not match format '%b %Y' (match)

Comment: i am getting this error now'

Comment: its difficult because we don't know the data type of the orginal date column... try doing "%b-%y" instead

Comment: date      object
spots    float64
dtype: object

Comment: do this, and tell me what you see print(df.date.iloc[0])

Comment: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date'
Thanks for helping but i am not getting it how to do that

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b %Y')
df = df.set_index('date')
print(df)

           spots
date            
1749-01-01  58.0
1749-02-01  62.6
1749-03-01  70.0
1749-04-01  55.7
1749-05-01  85.0
```